# kafka-server-start: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to start Kafka server on my Windows machine:

```
kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

But the process throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

But when I run:

```
kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

It looks like Kafka is not running:

> [2020-02-20 00:41:39,316] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1]
>   Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be
>   established. Broker may not be available.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2020-02-20 00:41:41,464]
>   WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1
>   (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be
>   available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2020-02-20
>   00:41:43,614] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to
>   node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker
>   may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

And also when I run `kafka-server-stop.bat`:

> No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: Well, sounds like you have a rouge process... Try using Task Manager to find it. Sidenote: Kafka is not tested against Windows. Have you tried using Docker or a VM?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried restart and I keep getting the same error. There is nothing starts with k in the processes. I will try docker.

Comment: So the error says it cannot access some **file**. For example, you have Windows Explorer open to some folder and it cannot be removed / written while that window is open

Comment: @cricket_007 Kafka is now running succesfully in a Docker container. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer with the steps you followed